# Where does dotPeek store it's cache?

Tags: caching, dotpeek

I was using dotPeek and my connection dropped right when it was going online to get some code for a given class. So my router has supplied it with 500 gateway page and now whenever I try to look at the code for that class I instead get an  html view of that router page i.e. its been cached.

The problem is there doesn't seem to be any way to clear it. I've deleted everything in AppData for JetBrains for both roaming and local but to no effect.

Where is the disassembly cache for dotPeek?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well thank heavens for process monitor. It stores it's cache in a directory like so:

> C:\Users\rism\AppData\Local\Symbols\src\source.NET\4\DEVDIV_TFS\Dev10\Releases\RTMRel\ndp\fx\src\xsp\System\Web\Routing\RouteCollection.cs

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For me, version 1.2 stores in C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\dotPeek\v1.2\DecompilerCache

Comment: This sounds correct for the decompiled code, different versions in subdirs, to simplify use `%localappdata%\JetBrains\dotPeek\`

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version (2017.1.2), it appears to be in:

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\DecompilationTemp

Comment: Sounds like `%temp%\DecompilationTemp` nothing there for me in 2019

Comment: Double clicking pdb file in symbol source window opens its location